# Filtro que separe de un array solo usuarios que contengan números en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de usar un filtro que separe de un array solo nombres de usuarios que contengan números.

```
const array_usuario = ["Carlos","Juan","Jacinto87","Daniel99"]
```

y se espera una salida de

```
array_usuario = ["Jacinto87","Daniel99"]
```

Estuve leyendo documentación y hay un método como filter(), pero por mas que logo hacer la condición no me muestra la salida deseada, se agradece la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de `Array.prototype.filter()` y tambien de `String.prototype.match()` para validar una **expresión regular**. En este caso `\d` que revisa si existe por lo menos un digito del 0-9.

El resultado, una lista de usuarios que contienen numeros.

```
// lista de usuarios
const users = ['hola12', 'myname', 'test', 'jack123'];

// lista de usuarios que contienen un numero
const usersWithNumbers = users.filter((user) => user.match(/\d/));

console.log(usersWithNumbers); // ["hola12", "jack123"]
```

Si lo que necesitas es lo contrario solo hace falta negar la expresion regular:

```
// lista de usuarios
const users = ['hola12', 'myname', 'test', 'jack123'];

// lista de usuarios sin numeros
const usersWithoutNumbers = users.filter((user) => !user.match(/\d/));

console.log(usersWithoutNumbers); // ["myname", "test"]
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer], editar y explicar tu aporte le ayudará aún mas al autor de la pregunta y demás personas que consulten